# ltm package in R error

Tags: r

I am new to R and am having some issues with running IRT models in the ltm package. Once I load my data frame and try to run the ltm() function, I get the error "'data' must be either a numeric matrix or a data.frame, with at least two columns." My data definitely has more than two columns. I have tried converting to a matrix, and I have received the same error again. How do I fix this?
Thanks in advance for your help and patience!

Comment: We need to see at least some of your data and how it was generated, to help. Most likely issue is that column types are not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is your data frame is not entirely numeric. Try running str() on your dataframe to check that the column types are all numeric. Then exclude or transform columns that are non-numeric as appropriate.